# Xcode parse UITextView (multiple line breaks)

Tags: xcode, uitextview, line-breaks

Please can anybody help me with the following question? If the user writes bulleted text (multiple line breaks) in UITextView, how to detect the total number of line breaks?

The character \n (line break) doesn't appear in the content of UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the `\n` character doesn't appear on console if you `print(textView.text)` it is still there on the `text` property.

One way of counting how many line breaks is to split the string using `\n` and count the number of chunks - 1.

```
let numberOfLineBreaks = textView.text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n").count - 1
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Raphael Oliveira's answer it is not the desired answer.

I found it!

The magical line break character is \ \ n.

And the code is:

```
        NSString *string = [object valueForKey:@"textViewContent"];

        NSError *error = nil;

        NSRegularExpression *regularExpression =
        [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\n"
                                                  options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                    error:&error];

        NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regularExpression numberOfMatchesInString:string
                                                             options:0
                                                               range:NSMakeRange(0,[string length])];
        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)numberOfMatches);

        NSUInteger lines = numberOfMatches;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try looking for characters in 'new line character set' using `NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()` instead of just `"\n"`